# How to show full path of module

Tags: emacs, elisp

If I do this:

```
(message (format "===> %s loaded" (file-name-base load-file-name)))
```

I get just the basename of the file.

```
===> 0100-start loaded
```

If I do this:

```
(message (format "===> %s loaded" 'load-file-name))
```

I get:

```
===> load-file-name loaded
```

Not really what I want ...

If I do this:

```
(message (format "===> %s loaded" load-file-name))
```

I get:

```
===> nil loaded
```

No clue what is happening there. I though the variable `load-file-name` has the value of the module where it is used. And it somehow has it, otherwise I could not get the `(file-name-base load-file-name)`, but used by itself does not work. I probably need to backquote-forward-quote-and-precede-with-a-comma the variable name, but no idea how to do this. Elisp witchery.

What I want to get is:

```
===> /home/user1/.emacs.d/conf/0100-start.el loaded
```

How to get the full, absolute path of the lisp module? I though this was the job of `load-file-name`. How can I display it?

How can I **use** a variable in elisp?

Comment: This works on my machine: I create a test file where I put `(message (format "===> %s loaded" load-file-name))`. Then, I evaluate `(load "/tmp/test.el")` which logs `===> /tmp/test.el loaded` in the `*Messages*` buffer. `load-file-name` is only bound during the time the file is being loaded. Are you doing exactly the same steps in the first and third attempts?

Comment: Maybe you just want this: `(message "===> %s loaded" buffer-file-name)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, [`message`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Messages.html) can do formatting, so [`format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html) is not needed.

Second, when you quote a variable, like `'foo`, it is not evaluated, so you are not getting its value.

Third, <kbd>C-h f [file-name-base](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html) RET</kbd> should explain your first output.

Finally, the correct forma *inside the file being loaded* is

```
(message "===> %s loaded" load-file-name)
```

and the reason you see `nil` there is that it was not evaluated *during loading*. Please try <kbd>C-h v [load-file-name](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/How-Programs-Do-Loading.html) RET</kbd>.

Comment: Is there a way of having this work in both automatically loaded conf files (`init.el` et al), and evaluated buffers? If I use `load-file-name` it works in buffers loaded, but not in buffers evaluated. and if I use `buffer-file-name` it works in buffers evaluated, but not in buffers loaded. I want to display the full path of the file containing the emacs program, even if I am just evaluating a file currently opened in a bufffer. Or maybe I should evaluate a file, instead of evaluate a buffer, whenever I make changes that I want to activate? How to evaluate a file? I do `M-x eval-buffer`

Comment: how about `(or load-file-name buffer-file-name)`?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. My life as emacs user would be easier if I knew some lisp :(

Answer (score 3):

[Scoping Rules for Variable Binding](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-21-2.8/html_node/elisp_147.html)<sup>**1**</sup>:

> Local bindings in Emacs Lisp have indefinite scope and dynamic extent.
>   [...]
>
> - **Indefinite scope** means that any part of the program can potentially access the variable binding. Extent refers to when, as the program is executing, the binding exists.
> - **Dynamic extent** means that the binding lasts as long as the activation of the construct that established it.

<sup>(Emacs can also perform [lexical binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html))</sup>

When you `load` a file, something like this happens:

```
(defun load (file)
  (let ((load-file-name file))
    (do-load file)))
```

And so, `load-file-name` is only bound to `file` during the time the file is being loaded. When the code exists the scope of the `let`, the  binding is no more effective.

Note that if you did not `load` but [`require`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html) a module, then upon loading *Emacs will also register the module as being provided and will **not** reload it when calling `require` another time*. This might be the reason you get `nil` the third time (see [`unload-feature`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Unloading.html)).

In your module, you can define a global binding for your own symbol:

```
(defvar jeckyll2hide/module-path load-file-name)
```

Then, the first time you `load` (or `require`) your module, you will define a variable that will be globally bound to the value that is  locally bound to `load-file-name` during loading.

---

**1.** formatting and emphasis mine